# How to remove '*' sign on a field when dealing with crispy forms?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

So in the crispy form documentation(link here: https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#change-required-fields), it states that:

> Asterisks have an asteriskField class set. So you can hide it using
> CSS rule.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model, HitCountMixin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default_pics/default_post.jpg', upload_to='post_pics')

    # a teacher can have many blog posts
    author = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class BlogFrom(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'image']
        widgets = {
            'image': forms.FileInput(attrs={"class":"asteriskField"})
        }
        help_texts = {
            'image': 'If you do not set any image, one will be set automatically for you upon creation.'
        }
```

I am not sure how to proceed from here. Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

As described in the documentation you can either add `.asteriskField {display: none; }` to your css file if you use one. Or you can add `<style> .asteriskField {display: none; } </style>`
to the header of your template.